# Why signed int convert to unsigned int

Tags: c

Can you explain this moment? Why unsigned int doesn't convert to signed int.

```
signed int a = 100;
unsigned int b = 4294967295;
a-b; /// Why 'a' will be convert to unsigned? Explain pls
```

Comment: Because that's what the language says.

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8p1

Comment: Aside to the `a-b` issue:  `4294967295` is likely not an `int`, nor `unsigned`, but a `long` or `long long` and gets converted to an `unsigned`.

Comment: BTW: `a-b;` :statement has no effect: can be optimised out.

Comment: @Chux why 4294967295 is not unsigned?

Comment: @chux The question is not answered because the question is about why this rule was adopted in the Standard.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi 4294967295 is UINT_MX in his system.

Comment: @MaximPro: 4294967295 is a decimal constant, and the types of decimal constants are the smallest of `int`, `long int` and `long long int` that will hold the value (C11 §6.4.4.1 Integer constants, ¶5).  If the value was written 0xFFFFFFFF, then it would probably be an `unsigned int` (assuming 32-bit `int` type).

Comment: @MaximPro if you have 32-bit `int` the value `4294967295` *cannot* be converted to `int` because it is outside of its range.

Comment: @immibis And he asks why did the standard adopt this rule instead of converting to the signed type?

Comment: @WeatherVane Strictly speaking INT_MIN is also outside the range of non-negative numbers.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: But there's no useful answer other than 'K&R 1st Edition said so', and it was implemented because it seemed sensible to do it that way when the `unsigned` qualifier was added to C, somewhere in the early to mid 70s.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow which is why `limits.h` has `#define INT_MIN (-2147483647 - 1)`.

Comment: @MaximPro Are you asking what the conversion rule is with mixed `unsigned` and. `int`?  Or are you asking why the standard specified that `unsigned` should be used instead of `int` in mixed code?

Comment: @Chux second :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that's if C11 is in use - many people still use compilers defaulting to C89 mode, or even non-standard mode.

Comment: @M.M: That's the standard I quoted from.  C99 effectively (if not literally) says the same, and in the same section number.  C89 doesn't mention `long long`, of course (and the section number is different — §6.1.3.2): _The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be
represented. Unsuffixed decimal `int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int`: …_  It's interesting that the 'unsigned' alternative is lost in the C99 and C11 standards.

Comment: @MaximPro Guess: At the time (1970s), there were 3 flavors of `signed int` in common usage: 2'complement, 1's complement, sign-magnitude. Conversion `unsigned` to `int` is not easy to specify in a way that all 3 should behave in a common way that is easy for various platforms to implement. So `unsigned` to `int` conversion is implementation-defined  Conversion the other way is well defined and it goes to the one and only representation (aside from width) **and does not favor** one representation.  Converting to `unsigned` with mixed `int/unsigned`, code uses well defined neutral representation

Comment: Conversion is not the same as casting. Don't use unrelated tags.